# Kendo UI Grid - Excel like filtering

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In the new version of Telerik Kendo UI, the multi-select checkboxes option as part of the filtering menu was introduced.

My question is if there is a way to display the elements in the multi-select list sorted in a given way.

The filter is set like this:

```
filterable: {
    multi: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: apiUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            error: "error"
        },
    }
}
```

Another problem si that, if the columnMenu is set to active, the filtering is not working (it doesn't make any request to the server).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [sort](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-sort) options on the `DataSource`? It should allow you to sort by any field ascending or descending, or add a custom sorting function.

For example:

```
filterable: {
    multi: true,
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: apiUrl,
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            error: "error"
        },
        sort: {
            field: "name",
            dir: "asc"
        }
    }
}
```